# before and after hooks for a request in express (to be executed before any req and after any res)

Tags: node.js, express

ExpressJS middleware `req`, `res`, `next` have hooks like `.on` and `.pipe`.

But I'm looking for hooks for the `app.get` and `app.post` methods.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[`app.use()` and middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) can be used for "*before*" and a combination of the [`'close'`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_1) and [`'finish'`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) events can be used for "*after*."

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    function afterResponse() {
        res.removeListener('finish', afterResponse);
        res.removeListener('close', afterResponse);

        // action after response
    }

    res.on('finish', afterResponse);
    res.on('close', afterResponse);

    // action before request
    // eventually calling `next()`
});

app.use(app.router);
```

An example of this is the [`logger` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html), which will append to the log after the response by default.

Just make sure this "*middleware*" is used before `app.router` as order does matter.

Comment: It's also interesting, that `logger` listens to both `close` and `finish`. Supposedly that can be useful in some situations.

Comment: @vkurchatkin Using both can help with backwards compatibility as `'finish'` is new with Node 0.10 and [Streams2](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/). So, Express is using [`'close'`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.26/api/stream.html#stream_event_close_1) as well to support lower versions of Node.

Comment: Hmm, don't think so: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_1, http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish. Looks like `close` is emitted if connection was terminated berfore `res.end()` call and `finish` is emitted after `res.send()`

Comment: @vkurchatkin A bit of both, actually. Note that I wasn't linking to the latest version of the docs as the `'finish'` event didn't exist in a stable release before `v0.10.0`. Before that, both scenarios would emit a `'close'` event -- [`http.ServerResponse` (v0.8.26)](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.26/api/http.html#http_event_close_1) and [Writable Stream (v0.8.26)](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.26/api/stream.html#stream_event_close_1). But, you are right that `'close'` is more than just for backwards support and I've edited for it.

Comment: I used this code, and put it right after var app = express().  I used Crockford's decycle to write the request object to the console log.  Some of the stuff I know is in the request object doesn't appear.  I can change the request, and get a different response from the server, so I know the information is going through, but I can't see it.  Is Express, by itself before adding any filters, altering the object?  Rick

Comment: Is it necessary to remove the listener? When the response is finish, neither itself nor the listener will be used again, or will they?

Comment: @user659025 : Not sure if this was the OP's reason, but it is worth noting that different versions of Node work differently with regard to the response's `close` and `finish` events... Some versions will send the `finish` event and follow it with the `close` event, while the most recent version (at the moment 10.9) will either send `finish` *or* `close` (depending on whether the response is sent), but not both. Removing the listeners (in `afterResponse`) makes the code work correctly for all versions of node.