# Get response status code in a middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, http-status-codes

I am building an app in which I am trying to build my own logging system for each request.

For each request, I'd like to log the timestamp, the method used, the route, and finally the response code that has been sent to the client.

I have the following code for the moment :

```js
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(require('./lib/logging'));

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('hello world !');
});

app.listen(3001);

// ./lib/logging.js
const moment = require('moment');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const log = console.log;

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  let now = `[${chalk.green(moment().format('HH:mm:ss'))}]`;
  let method = chalk.magenta(req.method);
  let route = chalk.blue(req.url);
  let code = chalk.yellow(res.statusCode); // Always 200
  log(`${now} ${method} request received on ${route} ${code}`);
  next();
}
```

Unfortunately, even if I do `res.status(201).send('hello world')` It will always catch a `200` status code...
Is there a way to catch any response outgoing to the client and fetch its status code ?

Comment: Where is middleware calling?

Comment: In the index, before declaring the route `'/'. I tried putting the middleware after the routes but I don't think this is the solution

Comment: Your middlewares won't execute after you do res.send. Use the solution from the following question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175806/before-and-after-hooks-for-a-request-in-express-to-be-executed-before-any-req-a

Comment: Kinda off-topic, but I just realized how clumsy this is with express, and how easy with Koa. Anyway, I think for this use-case you might simply need to hook into the `finish` event instead of using middleware.

Comment: I still can't get status code even with the `res.on('finish', () => {console.log(res) /* undefined */})`

Comment: you can create middleware and override send function.

Comment: @NeilRichter i don't see where `res` is coming from in your event handler.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the `finish` event from the response was indeed the good solution. The problem was in the `finish` event callback, I just couldn't use the arrow function because it wouldn't bind the `this` keyword, and this is were was stored the response data.

So the following code is working :

```js
// ./lib/logging.js

const moment = require('moment');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const log = console.log;

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  let now = `[${chalk.green(moment().format('HH:mm:ss'))}]`;
  let method = chalk.magenta(req.method);
  let route = chalk.blue(req.url);
  res.on('finish', function() {
    let code = chalk.yellow(this.statusCode);
    log(`${now} ${method} request received on ${route} with code ${code}`);
  })

  next();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The Express response [extends](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/response.js#L42) the Node.js [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), so you can listen for the [`'finish'`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish) event:

> #### Event: 'finish'
>
> Emitted when the response has been sent. More specifically, this event is emitted when the last segment of the response headers and body have been handed off to the operating system for transmission over the network. It does not imply that the client has received anything yet.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.on('finish', () => {
    console.log(`Responded with status ${res.statusCode}`);
  });
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Create middleware and Override send function

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
    var send = res.send;
    res.send = function (body) {
        // Do something
        send.call(this, body);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you need to add some status codes in  the response

You can simply set status codes like this

```
let code = {
   serverError:500,
   forbidden:401
}

res.status(code.serverError).json({
  message:'Server error'
})
```

If you want to set in the middleware

**middleware.js**

```
const statuscode = function middleware(req,res,next){


    let code = {
       serverError:500,
       forbidden:401
    }

    req.statusCode =code.serverError
   next()

}

module.exports = {
  statuscode
}
```

In the **index.js**

```
const middleware = require('./middleware');

app.get('/',middleware.statuscode, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Code from middleware",req.statusCode);
  res.send('hello world !');
});
```

Comment: By doing this, it means I have to put the `middleware.statuscode` in each route, which I don't want. I can catch every requests, can't I catch every responses ?

Comment: Put the status codes in config file and use it where you need